# Do passive sentences have objects?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, objects, passive-voice

I was answering a question on ELL and I came across a question of my own, namely whether there are objects in passive sentences. In this case the sentence was,

> Bobby was ran [sic] over by Billy's car.

Is *car* the object in that sentence like I thought? Or if there is an object, is it something else?

Comment: (Side note: it should be "was **run** over".) I wouldn't say it is the object of the verb. Pronouns do take objective case in this position; sometimes noun phrases that come after prepositions like this are referred to as the object of the preposition. But I would say the sentence as a whole does not have an object.

Comment: Ok I'll keep that in mind

Comment: The sentence part "by Bill's car" is called passive agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **direct object** of an active verb is the noun or noun phrase that receives the action of the verb.  So in

> Billy's car ran over **Bobby**

Bobby is the unfortunate recipient of the verb, so "Bobby" is a direct object.

When the sentence is transposed to the passive, i.e., with a verb composed of a form of "to be" and a past participle:

> Bobby was run over by Billy's car

by definition, the subject receives the action of the verb, so there's no place for a direct object.  That's why sentences in the passive don't have them.

Note that there are objects of things other than verbs.  For example, prepositions.  In a passive sentence, the actor (formerly the subject in the active sentence) may be relegated to the object of the preposition *by*.

Answer (score 2):

Billy's car after the preposition ***by*** is called the ***agent*** in the passive. The agent is the person or thing that performs the action and is the subject of the active sentence.

It might look like an object as it is a complement (object) of the preposition.

Bobby is called the ***patient*** of the main verb and is a direct object of the verb in the active voice version of the sentence below.

> ***Billy's car (subject)*** ran over ***Bobby (object)***

Passive:

> ***Bobby (patient)*** was run over by ***Billy's car (agent)***.

This [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice) explains about the passive voice in detail.

Comment: Good link.   Headspinning topic!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if the passive is formed from an indirect object, we can keep the direct object?

> He gave me a new car.
>
> I was given a new car by him.